# Can this list comprehension be made more pythonic?

Tags: python, strings

Quite a specific question can the below code be made more clearer / pythonic in any way.

Essentially based on the condition of the string `x((len(x) / 3) - 1)`, I use this to extract out parts of the string.

```
def split_string(x):
    splitted_string = [x[counter*3:(counter*3)+3] for counter in range ((len(x) /3) - 1)]
    return splitted_string

>>> split_string('ABCDEFGHI')
['ABC', 'DEF']
```

Answer (score 6):

For integer division, use the `//` operator.  [In Python 3, `/` will do floating-point division.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/183870/1157100)

The task could be more succinctly accomplished using [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

Also, the goal of the function is not obvious.  Pythonic code would include a docstring explaining its purpose.

```
import re

def split_string(s):
    """
    Splits a string into a list, with each element consisting of
    three characters.  Any incomplete group at the end is discarded,
    and then the last complete group is also discarded.
    """
    return re.findall(r'.{3}', s)[:-1]
```

Answer (score 5):

I always try to evaluate my function and see if there's anything else that could enhance it.

You're already evenly splitting these strings, so why not add a default parameter, size to control the section size. You also don't take the last cut (*I'm guessing to avoid index error*), you can add that as a default parameter as well.

Also, just return the comprehension

```
def split_string(word, size = 3, trim = 1):
    return [word[ii*size:(ii+1)*size] for ii in range(len(word)/size - trim )]

>>> split_string('ABCDEFGHI')
['ABC', 'DEF']
>>> split_string('ABCDEFGHI',4)
['ABCD', 'EFGH']
>>> split_string('ABCDEFGHI',3,0)
['ABC', 'DEF','GHI']
>>> split_string('ABCDEFGHI',3,2)
['ABC']
```

Comment: Menaningful parameter names would be even better :)

Comment: @Morwenn I agree,.. I was just lazy :p

Answer (score 4):

The `range` command has a step argument.

```
def split_string(x):
    return [x[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(x) - 5, 3)]

>>> split_string('ABCDEFGHI')
['ABC', 'DEF']
```

I also used `i` instead of `counter` since it's shorter and `i` is the standard way of expressing an array index in most langauges.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but the behaviour is quite different from the original code.

Comment: It was just missing the `-1` on the end of the range.

Comment: @DavidHarkness It's still not equivalent to the original.

Comment: @200_success I corrected my correction.

Comment: @DavidHarkness There was still an off-by-one error, which I've fixed in [Rev 4](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/46852/4).